# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() throwing System.ArgumentNullException: 'Path cannot be null. Parameter name: path' exception. Why?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, serialization, json-deserialization

My class structure is as follows:

```
class AppDetails
{
    public String companyName { get; set; }
    public String applicationName { get; set; }
    public String version { get; set; }
    public List<File_> fileObjectList { get; set; }

    public AppDetails(String cName, String aName, String v)
    {
        companyName = cName;
        applicationName = aName;
        version = v;
    }
}

class File_
{
    public String filePath { get; set; }
    public FileRecord fileRecord { get; set; }
    public File_(String parent_, String filepath_, Boolean Ignored)
    {
        filePath = filepath_;
        fileRecord = new FileRecord(parent_ + filePath, Ignored);
    }
}

class FileRecord
{
    public Boolean ignored { get; set; }
    public String MD5Checksum { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }

    public FileRecord(String filePath, Boolean ignored_)
    {
        ignored = ignored_;
        if (ignored)
        {
            MD5Checksum = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MD5Checksum = CalculateMD5(filePath);
            version = 0;
        }
    }

    static string CalculateMD5(string filePath)
    {
        var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash((System.IO.Stream)stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();

    }

}
```

I generated Json file using these classes. But when I try to initialize an object with the said JSON file, it throws System.ArgumentNullException: 'Path cannot be null. Parameter name: path' exception.
This is the function that is supposed to return the object.

```
AppDetails ReadJsonFile()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText(parent + "\\AllFilesList.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppDetails>(json);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I tried generating the classes from JSON using online class generators and it matches my class structure. Exception is thrown on this line:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppDetails>(json);
```

Json string is getting loaded with the content from the file just fine(as can be seen from the watch). I couldn't find anything about Path issues related to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. Most previous questions seems to be related to value errors.

EDIT: Serialization Code

```
void JsonWriter(AppDetails appDetails, String filename)
    {
        string path = parent + "\\" + filename + ".json";
        File.Delete(path);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appDetails);
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(json.ToString());
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Sample Json File:

```
{"companyName":"Home","applicationName":"Test","version":"V5.0.1","fileObjectList":[{"filePath":"\\bug-tracker.exe","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"a5254a813a040b429f2288df737a8b9f","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\bug-tracker.exe.config","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"e5c3e9137dc8fadb57dfc27b0ba6855c","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\bug-tracker.pdb","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"9a9dfda29dcaacae82cba7bd7aa97ffa","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\Caliburn.Micro.dll","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"aa5f96c02b08d9b33322f3024058dd91","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core.dll","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"ab7867bd44b59879a59b5cb968e15668","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core.xml","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"cdfcbbf70a9a62b92e82a953ab9e7e30","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.dll","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"a52bdecbc1b7625cb13c9385fad4231b","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.xml","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"09f258a3aeca7285355d82a66dda2176","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\Caliburn.Micro.xml","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"c87ec582a4bfcf2e79e517c689441def","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\MaterialDesignColors.dll","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"ad729352a9088b889cc0c4dc7542dcb6","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\MaterialDesignColors.pdb","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"7ba70b23e22db9ac155e190860d9a5ec","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"e4c790d3af41620dc5ad513ae7fcadac","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.pdb","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"f8113c8ea54896b8150db8e7ebd506ef","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.xml","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"49717f8130b7529ee51fb6bc13f79aa4","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\ShowMeTheXAML.dll","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"040b9e80820553a55f13ac19c2036367","version":0}},{"filePath":"\\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll","fileRecord":{"ignored":false,"MD5Checksum":"580244bc805220253a87196913eb3e5e","version":0}}]}
```

Edit 2: Json String from watch

```
"{\"companyName\":\"Home\",\"applicationName\":\"Test\",\"version\":\"V5.0.1\",\"fileObjectList\":[{\"filePath\":\"\\\\bug-tracker.exe\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"a5254a813a040b429f2288df737a8b9f\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\bug-tracker.exe.config\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"e5c3e9137dc8fadb57dfc27b0ba6855c\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\bug-tracker.pdb\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"9a9dfda29dcaacae82cba7bd7aa97ffa\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\Caliburn.Micro.dll\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"aa5f96c02b08d9b33322f3024058dd91\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core.dll\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"ab7867bd44b59879a59b5cb968e15668\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core.xml\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"cdfcbbf70a9a62b92e82a953ab9e7e30\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.dll\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"a52bdecbc1b7625cb13c9385fad4231b\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.xml\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"09f258a3aeca7285355d82a66dda2176\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\Caliburn.Micro.xml\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"c87ec582a4bfcf2e79e517c689441def\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\MaterialDesignColors.dll\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"ad729352a9088b889cc0c4dc7542dcb6\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\MaterialDesignColors.pdb\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"7ba70b23e22db9ac155e190860d9a5ec\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"e4c790d3af41620dc5ad513ae7fcadac\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.pdb\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"f8113c8ea54896b8150db8e7ebd506ef\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.xml\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"49717f8130b7529ee51fb6bc13f79aa4\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\ShowMeTheXAML.dll\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"040b9e80820553a55f13ac19c2036367\",\"version\":0}},{\"filePath\":\"\\\\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll\",\"fileRecord\":{\"ignored\":false,\"MD5Checksum\":\"580244bc805220253a87196913eb3e5e\",\"version\":0}}]}\r\n"
```

Comment: What is `parent`? Looks like your stream reader is trying to open a file that doesn't exist. Put a breakpoint, inspect what path you are trying to open, then make sure that file is there.

Comment: Could you please add a serialization code as well? It would be good to check the content of the serialized file as well.

Comment: `Parent` is rest of the path. And after `string json = r.ReadToEnd();` json is populated with the contents of the file. So I am guessing that the file is getting read just fine.

Comment: Added Serialization code and the Json file.

Comment: Add default (empty) constructors to your File and FileRecord classes, or mark properties with JsonProperty attribute. Serializer uses your constructors when deserialing, but constructor parameter names do not match json property names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue is that you have the parameters in your constructor:

```
public FileRecord(String filePath, Boolean ignored_)
```

And *JsonConvert* puts there default values *(null, false)* which triggers the code:

```
else
{
    MD5Checksum = CalculateMD5(filePath);
    version = 0;
}
```

Which in its turn tries to read from a file using *null* path parameter:

```
static string CalculateMD5(string filePath)
    {
        var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath); // <- HERE!!!!
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash((System.IO.Stream)stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();

    }
```

I see there two solutions

- Create parameterless constructors where init everything as you need or call the constructor with parameters using *:this()* with defaults:

  public FileRecord() : this(null, true)
  {
  }
- Rename properties to match parameter names, like:

  ```
   public bool Ignored { get; set; }

   public FileRecord(string filePath, bool ignored)
   {
        this.Ingnoerd = ignored;
        ....
   }
  ```

Comment: Good catch, but in your answer you should also provide a solution (for instance defining a default constructor `public FileRecord()`)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes! Adding default constructors solved the issue.